# Don't redirect unacceptable questions to other sites

Tags: discussion, migration

We had a new user [ask a question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/127657/first-game-program)(10K only) that was most decidedly off-topic for us.  Due to it being about Game Development, some users took it upon themselves to redirect them to GameDev.SE.  So the user self-deleted his question here, and re-asked it there, word for word.  [Where it promptly also got closed](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/60835/first-time-game-development) for being off-topic, due to it being an area they've determined they don't support.

We [just got another one](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/130391/creating-minecraft-game), that [instantly got closed](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/61957/creative-minecraft-game-inventory-bug) over at GameDev.  Let's not automatically suggest GameDev as the place to ask just because the question has code, shall we?

I get that we're trying to be helpful by pointing out where their questions may be acceptable, but we're not helping them at all by just saying, "Try asking here."  They take our advice, and it gets closed there, too, leading to some bad blood, since we told them to go ask it there.

If a question is clearly off-topic here, and you know it's on-topic somewhere else, by all means, go ahead and leave a comment to redirect them there.  If you're unsure, though, try to do some research of the target site.  They have their own standards, which may not match ours.  If you have to point them at a target site, try to point out what they'll need to change to make it acceptable over there.  Clean up any spelling or grammar errors you see.

If you're still unsure if it belongs there, and it certainly doesn't belong here, flag it for migration, using the Other box.  There's a reason mods can migrate questions.  If a question has been asked on the wrong site in the StackExchange network, they can discuss it with the target site's mods before initiating a transfer.  We do nobody, least of all ourselves, any favors by telling new users to go ask it somewhere else if it's also off-topic there.  Same as the rule of, "Don't migrate low quality content", we should include, "Don't redirect low quality content".

Comment: The question in question was entirely about soliciting discussion. This is not allowed on *any* stack exchange site. We very explicitly do QA, not discussion.

Comment: Exactly.  So we should not be redirecting it at all.

Comment: Yup. **Rule #1 for migrations -- don't migrate crap!**

Comment: @fbueckert Recommending education to new users that helps them understand the rules of the stack network, and recommending against taking an automatic action that will cause them a bad experience.  I like it.