# Instead of closing this question, how about migrating it to GameDev?

Tags: discussion, closing, migration

This question was closed four years ago.

[Why do console games require a button press before showing the main menu?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/18780/why-do-console-games-require-a-button-press-before-showing-the-main-menu)

But this has existed for eleven years now:

https://gamedev.stackexchange.com

So instead of closing this highly-voted question, why wasn't it migrated to Game Development.SE?

Comment: Related: [Don't redirect unacceptable questions to other sites](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/7529/143571)

Comment: That's only related if it is, in fact, an unacceptable question.  Do you have a reason to believe it is?

Comment: It's still related, I'm not saying it's a duplicate.

Answer (score 5):

We're not really in the habit of migrating 10 year old questions, especially ones with several answers, with an asker that has been inactive for over 2 years. If you feel that none of the answers are satisfactory, and you would like some additional answers, then I'd encourage you to just [ask your own question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) over at [GameDev.SE](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/).

Additionally, it's important to note that this question has been locked with  the **Historical Lock.** This is a special type of question lock that moderators can use to preserve high quality content which used to be acceptable on the site, but no longer meets our current site scope or standards. It's primarily intended to be used on questions from the very early days of a site, when that site was still figuring out it's scope. Due to this, the question is in no danger of being deleted.

Comment: Also: we can't migrate anything that's older than (IIRC) 6 months anyway.